# Enum list to STL container

Tags: c++, enum, stl

Can someone improve upon this function of mine?  `EnumToSTLContainer` is supposed to make a copy of any STL container whose elements are from a specified `enum` list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

enum MyEnum {A, B, C, D, E, FirstMyEnum = A, LastMyEnum = E};

template <typename CONTAINER>
CONTAINER EnumToSTLContainer (typename CONTAINER::value_type first, typename CONTAINER::value_type last) {
    CONTAINER v;
    for (int N = first;  N <= last;  N++)
        v.push_back(static_cast<typename CONTAINER::value_type>(N));  // But only works for STL containers with push_back defined.
    return v;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<MyEnum> enumVector = EnumToSTLContainer<std::vector<MyEnum>> (FirstMyEnum, LastMyEnum);
    for (MyEnum x : enumVector)
        std::cout << x << ' ';  // 0 1 2 3 4
//  const std::set<MyEnum> enumSet = EnumToSTLContainer<std::set<MyEnum>> (FirstMyEnum, LastMyEnum);  // won't compile
}
```

This only works for STL containers with `push_back()` defined, and need to specify first and last element of the enum list. It does not work if `enum` values are not consecutive.

Perhaps obtaining an `initializer_list` using variadic templates would work, which can then return the desired STL container?

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use [`std::underlying_type_t<Cont::value_type>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) instead of `int` and please don't use `UPPER` for template parameters (`UPPER` is mostly for preprocessor, sometimes used for constants and/or static variables), rather use `PascalCasing`, e.g. `Container`.

Your implementation looks good to me otherwise, but you know it can only be used with containers with member `push_back`. If you want to create it from `initializer_list`, then it would be something different (e.g. `EnumRangeInitList`). You may find some inspiration in [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).